# Concurrency on keys in a sync map

Tags: go, synchronization

Trying to use a sync map in golang to provide ability to acquire a lock on a particular string(say "LOCK1").

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var lockMap sync.Map
func main(){

    counter := func(key string,routineId string) {
        _,ok := lockMap.Load(key)
        if(ok){
            fmt.Println(key+ " skipped by "+ routineId)
            return}

        lockMap.Store(key,true)
        defer lockMap.Delete(key)
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(key+ " locked by "+ routineId)
        }
    }

    // Starting some goroutines
    go counter("LOCK1","routine1")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine2")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine3")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine4")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine5")
    //adding some sleep so the  routines can execute for sometime
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```

I am aware that sync map uses a RWMutex under the hood.
But, I am trying to understand if sync map allows multiple writes on different keys at the same time or only a single routine can do a write on the entire map at one time?

So let's say the key "LOCK1" is being set by routine1, would routine2 be able to set a new value "LOCK2" concurrently or does it have to wait for the first write to finish.

Comment: If you want locking, you need to use locks (e.g., mutex). Checking for key existence is not a substitute for locking.

Comment: But I want a lock on a pre-defined key and not a general Mutex.

Comment: You can have a unique mutex associated with each key

Comment: But I don't know how many keys will be needed ahead of time.

Comment: [`sync.Map.LoadOrStore`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map.LoadOrStore) will be useful. You can atomically load the existing value or insert a new one if it doesn't exist already.

Comment: hmm but my question is would it be possible to use the the same sync map to write across different keys without contention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each key, you want to access the existing lock, or create a new lock if there isn't one. With [`sync.Map.LoadOrStore`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#Map.LoadOrStore) you can do this atomically.

```golang
// Pre-allocate a new lock, in case it's needed for this key.
newLockIfNeeded = new(sync.Mutex)
lock, _ = lockMap.LoadOrStore(key, newLockIfNeeded)
// Safely acquired the (potentially new) lock for the key
lock.Lock()
defer lock.Unlock()
// do work ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to provide a direct answer to OP

> sync map allow multiple writes on different keys at the same time?

**Yes, but under specific conditions**

sync.Map is optimized for unique writes with many readers. It is slow for having many routines update the same key (see [sync.Map use cases](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/sync/map.go#L20)). Internally it contains a read map, a dirty map, and atomic read/writes to pointers. Some operations use a mutex, while others bypass it for speed.

---

**Yes, simultaneous ***writes/deletes*** are allowed only if**

- The key already existed (`m.read.Load()`)

  - `atomic.LoadPointer` gets the fast read map, but callers can still arrive at the next step together
- The above key wasn't or isn't being updated/deleted

  - Wasn't updated: sync.Map checks the `expunged` pointer to see if it was updated elsewhere
  - Isn't being updated: key was not changed while checking if it was expunged (`CompareAndSwapPointer`)

**Yes, simultaneous ***reads*** are allowed if either**

- The key does not exist while no new keys were added
- The key exists and is not being updated (like above)

**No, a mutex lock is used when**

- Storing a new key

  - Example: bulk adding distinct keys is slow
- Loading a missing key after a new key was added

  - Example: frequent deleting and checking for deleted is slow
- Reading or writing a key that is being updated

  - Example: many updating the same key is slow

**However, the mutex does not block the Yes cases**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a sync map of key -> mutex. Thanks for the pointers Hymns for Disco. For reference here is the working impl:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

//var lockMap sync.Map
var lockMap2 sync.Map
func main(){

    //lockMap2 := make(map[string]*sync.Mutex)
    counter := func(key string,routineId string) {
        mutex,_ := lockMap2.LoadOrStore(key,&sync.Mutex{})
        mutex.(*sync.Mutex).Lock()
        defer mutex.(*sync.Mutex).Unlock()
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            fmt.Println(key+ " locked by "+ routineId)
        }
    }

    // Starting some goroutines
    go counter("LOCK1","routine1")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine2")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine3")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine4")
    go counter("LOCK1","routine5")
    //adding some sleep so the  routines can execute for sometime
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}
```